# Is It Possible to Create Nuget Package for only a Single Namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nuget

I would like to create a Nuget package for a single namespace within a project. My MVC project has many namespaces. The namespace has a significant repository class.

Then I want to refer to the namespace in a totally different solution on a different computer. Is this possible, or are Nuget packages only on the Project level?

Comment: Nuget packages distribute dlls (for the most part) . Unless your namespace is entirely contained in its own separate dll from everything else, then you can't distribute it on its own

Comment: so would I make the Repository a single project, make it a class Library, and then nugetize the one project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a [.nuspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) file to add files to nuget package and use [`nuget pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack)
Or
You can create a project referencing all projects and code of your namespace you need to package and use [`dotnet pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x) or `nuget pack`

Comment: so in this case, all the files related to the repository? Is there a command to find all files under a certain namespace?

Comment: nope, and you shouldn't package codes but libraries

Comment: @MarkThomas I added another solution in my answer