# Is it Possible to Create Nuget Package for Single Project in a Solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nuget

Do Nuget packages only work on a Solution level?

Or is it possible to create nuget packages for only Specific Projects in a solution? I have a single project which I want to nugetize, and would like to ignore the rest.

Comment: Yes, you can do only specific projects. You could even make a package for a single static text file. It is very flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`dotnet pack <PROJECT>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x) to create a nuget package of a .Net Core project

Comment: cool thank you!  also left one similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905267/c-sharp-is-it-possible-to-create-nuget-package-for-only-a-single-namespace

Comment: @MarkThomas If this answer respond to your question you should accept it...

Comment: @aguafrommars what about the full .net framework? Can we do the same `dotnet pack` for it?

Comment: @user246392 if your app is a dotnet core app, then yes.